# Iterate through numbers between two set min and max values

Tags: javascript, loops

I am making a javascript loop that makes certain elements change color very subtlely every time the loop runs. The value I am changing is the L value of an HSL color.

Right now I have this.

```
var h = 10,
s = 0.5,
l = 1 / ((i += 0.01) % 10);

color = hsl(h, s, l);
```

Right now this outputs colors going from light to dark, starting over whenever it hits black (because of the modulo operation).

The L value must be between 0 and 1, however I would like to cap the outputs of my operation to be between 0.1 and 0.9 to avoid the too dark and too bright colors.
Does anyone know how to tweak the operation to fit these requirements?

Also I would like to know if someone knows how to make the output reverse (instead of start over from the top) every time it hits min or max, meaning that it outputs numbers like this:

0.9...0.89...[...]...0.11...0..1...0.11...[...]...0.89...0.9...0.89 and so on

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can cap the output value between 0 and 1 to between 0.1 and 0.9 by:

```
cappedValue = 0.1 + 0.8 * uncappedValue
```

For bouncing the value between 0 and 1 you can use

```
boundcingValue = Math.abs(1 - 2 * valueBetween0and1)
```

so the resulting solution would be:

```
var h = 10,
s = 0.5,
l = 1 / ((i += 0.01) % 10);

lbouncing = Math.abs(1 - 2 * l);
lcapped = 0.1 + lbouncing * 0.8;

color = hsl(h, s, lcapped);
```

haven't tested it though...

Comment: Thank you! Well it sort of works. I am however still getting some all-white streaks meaning that the output value for some reason is 1 or above. I can't quite figure out why this i happening.

Comment: your calculation of l will exceed 1 when i is below 1. I think this is what you mean: l = l + 0.01; and then below that: if (l > 1) l = 0;

Comment: Well I'm still not getting exactly what I want. I am working on a solution and will provide this whenever I'm there.